# Reporting Services, Custom Percent Format

Tags: reporting-services, formatting

I have some fields I currently populate with a P0.  The results is like this:

```
2,434%
```

I want however something like this:

```
2434%
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      ####%
```

Note: Unfortunately, this does not lock down to a max of 4 characters (like I would expect/wanted), but it's close enough.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried something like 0000%? Or alternatively, an expression like:

```
=right(format(Fields!YourField.Value,"#%"),5).
```

I don't have BI studio open right now so I can't test these. The expression would of course convert the value to text, which maybe problematic when you export the report to excel.